# Delete duplicate record in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

| ColA | ColB | ColC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 12 |
| A | 2 | 12 |
| A | 3 | 12 |
| B | 1 | 12 |
| B | 2 | 12 |
| B | 3 | 12 |
| C | 1 | 12 |
| C | 2 | 12 |
| C | 3 | 12 |

I have such table data. And expect result is:

| ColA | ColB | ColC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 12 |
| B | 2 | 12 |
| C | 3 | 12 |

or

| ColA | ColB | ColC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3 | 12 |
| B | 2 | 12 |
| C | 1 | 12 |

or

| ColA | ColB | ColC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 12 |
| B | 3 | 12 |
| C | 2 | 12 |

If there are 4 record inserted, then it will join and become 16(4*4) records in final temp table. How do I delete unnecessary data in this case?
This is what tried

```sql
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY Col2) AS Row_count 
  FROM table_1
)
DELETE FROM cte WHERE rn<>1;
```

And I got:

| ColA | ColB | ColC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 12 |
| B | 1 | 12 |
| C | 1 | 12 |

which is wrong.

`ColB` data should be not be duplicated.
After deleting, every record must be unique.

Comment: Does this table have a `PRIMARY KEY`? What is the full `CREATE TABLE` statement - and how did you get this duplicate data in the first place?

Comment: This is a temporary data. And it is not having primary key. After proper data this will be insert into another table. And I can't make changes in that table using Alter statement. So I have choose proper data from Temp table.

Comment: Do all the rows of this table have the same value 12 in the column ColC?

Comment: Yes everything is same except those two columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use combination of two partitions and check for differences:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ColA ORDER BY ColB) AS Row_count1, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ColB ORDER BY ColA) AS Row_count2 
  FROM table_1
)
DELETE FROM   cte WHERE Row_count1<>Row_count2
```

See the db fiddle here
https://dbfiddle.uk/aLsQLHIt

Answer (score 1):

For this sample data all you need is `DENSE_RANK()` window function to get a group number for each value of `ColA`:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ColA) rn FROM t)
DELETE FROM cte WHERE ColB <> rn;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/DkoGFFZ-).

Answer (score 0):

I'd to rank lines twice: first time on colB, colC and on colA so, the intermediate results would be:

| ColA | ColB | ColC | rank_bc | rank_a |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 12 | 1 | 1 |
| A | 2 | 12 | 2 | 1 |
| A | 3 | 12 | 3 | 1 |
| B | 3 | 12 | 3 | 2 |
| B | 2 | 12 | 2 | 2 |
| B | 1 | 12 | 1 | 2 |
| C | 1 | 12 | 1 | 3 |
| C | 2 | 12 | 2 | 3 |
| C | 3 | 12 | 3 | 3 |

After that all is left to do is just to filter lines with rank_bc = rank_a

```
with test_data_ranked as (  
select ColA, ColB, ColC, 
       dense_rank() over (order by colB, colC) rank_bc,
       dense_rank() over (order by colA) rank_a
  from test_data)

select colA, colB, colC
  from test_data_ranked
 where rank_bc = rank_a;
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gjnKIjkt)

Answer (score 0):

You Can solve your problem with cte and window function with use query store

```
;WITH cte AS (

select *,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY Rw  order by ColB ) AS Rwn from (
  SELECT *, 
         row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ColB  order by colA ) AS Rw
  FROM Ta
  )d

)
delete  FROM cte WHERE Rwn>1;
```

Result:

| ColA | ColB | ColC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 12 |
| B | 1 | 12 |
| C | 1 | 12 |

Comment: This is what I got too. I want ColB value different for every record. :)